# Aligning two widgets with css and html

Tags: html, css

I have two widgets I'd like to align[https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q6Z4.png How can I go about aligning them with css and html?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.  And what do you mean by align?  Tops aligned?  Bottoms Aligned?  Centerlines Aligned? ...

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to add the following CSS code to the twitter container:

```
.twitter-container {
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
}
```

Of course, it would help if you can provide us with your code

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix">
   <div class="snippet-one"></div>
   <div class="snippet-two"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clearfix {
  display:table;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
.snippet-one,
.snippet-two {
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I added this to my stylesheet and worked, but distorted my webpage, renaming it to clearfix2 worked though.